# Show that $\left(2n\right)!\leq \left(n\left(n+1\right)\right)^{n}$.

Tags: inequality

Show that $\left(2n\right)!\leq \left(n\left(n+1\right)\right)^{n}$.

My attempt so far:

$\left(2n \right)!=1\cdot2\cdot...\cdot\left(2n-1\right)\cdot2n\leq\left(n\left(n+1\right)\right)^{n}=\left(n^{2}+n\right)^{n}$

This is where I am stuck. I know that his holds for some values of $n$, such as 2, but I am having a hard time proceeding from here. I am not sure if induction would be the best approach or if there would be a more elegant solution. Thanks in advance for any hints.

Comment: Normally, I would give this response as an answer.  However, in this case, it would be lost in the shuffle.  See [AM-GM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $1\leq i \leq n$ we have $i(2n-i+1) \leq n^{2}+n$. This is because  $n^{2}-(2i-1)n+i^{2}-i =(n-(i-\frac1  2))^{2}+i^{2}-i- (i-\frac1  2)^{2}\geq 0$. [ I have used the fact that $|n-(i-\frac  12)| \geq \frac1  2$ which gives $(n-(i-\frac  12))^{2} \geq \frac1  4$].

Now just mulptly the inequalities $i(2n-i+1) \leq n^{2}+n$ for $i=1,2,...,n$.

Answer (score 2):

Ross Millikan has perhaps the slickest approach, but if one doesn’t see it, one can also prove the result by induction on $n$. We can check the cases $n=0,1,2$ by hand. Suppose that $n\ge 2$, and $(2n)!\le n^n(n+1)^n$.

$$\frac{(2(n+1))!}{(2n)!}=2(n+1)(2n+1)\,,$$

and

$$\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}(n+2)^{n+1}}{n^n(n+1)^n}=\frac{(n+1)(n+2)^{n+1}}{n^n}\,,$$

so we’re done if we can show that

$$2(n+1)(2n+1)\le\frac{(n+1)(n+2)^{n+1}}{n^n}\,,$$

i.e., that

$$\frac{4n+2}{n+2}\le\left(\frac{n+2}n\right)^n\,.$$

And this follows from the binomial theorem:

$$\begin{align*}
\left(\frac{n+2}n\right)^n&=\left(1+\frac2n\right)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}k\left(\frac2n\right)^k\\
&\ge 1+n\cdot\frac2n+\frac{n(n-1)}2\cdot\frac4{n^2}\\
&=3+\frac{2n-2}n\\
&=5-\frac2n\\
&\ge 4\\
&\ge 4-\frac6{n+2}\\
&=\frac{4n+2}{n+2}
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 1):

You are done, but should probably put some words in to support the $\le$ sign.  Break the product on the left up into pairs of numbers, taking the highest and lowest off the run to make the pairs.  There are $n$ pairs and each one is less than $n(n+1)$

Comment: Thank you for the input. So would the pairs be something like this: $1\cdot 2n, 2 \cdot 2n-1,...,\left(2n-1\right)*2n$?

Comment: The first two are correct, but the last one is $n\cdot (n+1)$ as you are working your way in from each end.  You should also have parentheses around $2n-1$ in the second one.

Comment: @ChairmanMeow you have to give a formal proof of the fact that the product of each pair does not exceed $n^{2}+n$. This is what I have done in my answer.

Comment: "You are done"? I think the OP merely wrote down the goal ...

Answer (score 1):

$$\left(2n\right)!\leq \left(n\left(n+1\right)\right)^{n}$$
$$\log((2n)!) \leq n \log(n(n+1))$$ Using Stirling approximation for the lhs and Taylor for the rhs
$$\text{lhs}=n (2 \log (n)-2+2\log (2))+\frac{1}{2} \log (4 \pi  n)+\frac{1}{24
   n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$
$$\text{rhs}=2 n \log (n)+1-\frac{1}{2 n}+\frac{1}{3
   n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$
$$\text{rhs- lhs}= 2(1-\log (2))n+\left(1-\frac{1}{2} \log (4 \pi  n)\right)-\frac{13}{24
   n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

The Simplest way is as fallows 
You can write down the inequality as:
$$ (2n)! \le (n^2+n)^n $$
Since $ n \ge 1 $:
$$ 2n \le n^2+n $$
$$ (2n)^n \le  (n^2+n)^n $$
Also:
$$ (2n)! \le (2n)^n $$
So:
$$ (2n)! \le (n^2+n)^n $$

Comment: I wanted to write exactly this answer. So +1.

Comment: However, I would suggest you remove the first sentence. It is not quite justifiable -- what's more, it doesn't serve any positive purpose.

Comment: -1 Can you explain why $ (2n)! \leq (2n) ^n$? For example, with $n =2 $, we have $ 24 < 16$ isn't a true statement. Does it hold for some large enough $n$? Stirling's approximation tells us that we'd likely want something involving $(2n) ^ { 2n}$, so I'd be surprised if $(2n)^n$ was sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Since
$n! < n(n/e)^n$,
$(2n)! < 2n(2n/e)^{2n}$,
so we want
$2n(2n/e)^{2n}
\lt (n^2+n)^n
$
or
$(2n)^{1/n}(2n/e)^2
\lt n^2+n
$.

This is true if
$(2n)^{1/n}(2n/e)^2
\lt n^2
$
or
$(2n)^{1/n}
\lt e^2/4
$.

Since
$(2x)^{1/x}$
is decreasing for
$x > e/2$
and
$(2n)^{1/n}
\lt e^2/4$
for $n = 3$,
(since
$(e^2/4)^3
=e^6/64
\gt 6.3$)
we are done.